# dc.js rowChart - make entire row clickable?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I've got a dc.js rowChart (using the current stable release).  It's beautiful.  I need it to be more touch-friendly though.

In particular, rows with small values have very tiny bars and are very hard to tap.  What I'd like to do it make it such that the user can click anywhere on a row to select/deselect that row rather than having to click directly on the bar.

Is this possible?

Comment: The labels are clickable, One workaround is to have a label of a good enough length such that even if the row rectangle is tiny, the labels can be easily seen and clicked. I am trying to find a solution to your problem though. Will update soon as a find anything.

Comment: Good point about the labels, @anmolkoul. I imagine an invisible element could also be added behind the entire row area in a renderlet, and then also given the `.on("click", ...)`. I could give it a try later in the week, hopefully anmol will come up with something sooner. :-)

Comment: @Gordon You did it.. Like a Boss! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a very hacky solution, I was able to add a bunch of non-breaking spaces after the label and get this effect:

```
.label(function (d) { return /* your label here */ + new Array(100).join('\xa0'); })
```

(An invisible element would be better.)

Comment: cool, definitely hacky but absent a better solution it seems to be working.  btw, here's how i ended up doing the nbsp: `var nbspPadding = (new Array(100)).join('\xA0'); `

Comment: Ah yes the hex character escape sequence. That's what I was looking for. Correcting my answer... Glad it worx!