# dc.js barChart - click on x-axis ticks and labels

Tags: dc.js

i am using dc.js (2.0.0-beta.32) for several bar charts, which may happen to display bars whose values differ of 2-3 orders of magnitude, making smaller values' bars almost zero-height, which are almost impossible to click reliably.

i can somehow mitigate this by using a non-linear scale for the bars' height, though this is not really useful because of other constraints i have on data and charts across the project.

adding labels via `.label()` is not doable either because of the layout i have to work within.

unless i am missing something obvious, i can't see a way to make the *x axis* tick labels themselves clickable (rather than labels on top of bars added via `.label()`): is there any way to make selection of *columns* (as in, bar + associated tick label)?

the closest solution i have found is this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30560518/550077
though again not really usable in my chart layout which includes 40-50 narrow bars (it's a small improvement but clicking is still not as reliable as it could be by clicking on tick labels)

Comment: Good idea. Two things that make this not simple: the axis is drawn by d3, not dc.js, so we'll have to select elements created by the other library. Also, only the ordinal charts guarantee that there will be one tick per bar.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of messy, but if you know how to map the x domain to your data, you can add your own click handlers to the axis.

For example, on [the filtering example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/filtering.html), you can add a handler like this:

```
spendHistChart.select('.axis.x')
    .selectAll('.tick text')
    .on('click', function(d) {
        spendHistChart.replaceFilter(new dc.filters.RangedFilter(d, d+1)); 
        spendHistChart.redrawGroup();
    });
```

As noted [on the user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dc-js-user-group/blDeX7JBvxE/pvfP9UondYsJ), you'll also need to enable `pointer-events` for ticks, since they're disabled by dc.css by default.

Note that the above assumes a chart with a linear scale. If you're dealing with an ordinal scale, the call may be as simple as `.replaceFilter(d)`, but again, it depends on the mapping from your x domain to your actual data.